# java ArrayList grid use of get method

Tags: java, arraylist

Not sure if this is commonly used, because I have seen Array grid.

```
List<Object> LL1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2));
List<Object> LL2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6));
List<Object> LL3 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9));
List<Object> Lgrid = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(LL1, LL2, LL3));
System.out.println(Lgrid);  // >>> [[1, 2], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

So I create a ArrayList grid, no problem.
Now, if I want to add a value into 1st element of the grid, (LL1).

```
// I can:
LL1.add(3);
// But I can't:
Lgrid.get(0).add(3);
```

I believe if it is an Array grid, I can do this, at least edit by calling `Array[0][0] = newValue`.

Is there anyway for me to just handle things from the grid?

Thanks!

Comment: `LL1.add(3);` this will throw Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: *"But I can't: `Lgrid.get(0).add(3)`" ... you could if you would stop using raw types.

Comment: @Deadpool Why should it?

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` will return unmodifable list https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-

Comment: @Deadpool Cool and then pass that unmodifiable list into the `ArrayList` constructor and you get? ... a modifiable list :)

Comment: Code_Control, about your edit: why do you want to shot yourself in to the foot? Why do you use `List<Object>`? You __want__ to interact with the inner list and still trick Java into believing it is just an ordinary object? Why?

Comment: guys, I added all `<Object>` back, didn't know that it could impact. But the answer pointed out that I should use `List<List>`, and that solves the problem! Thank you all.

Comment: @Tom  That was a mistake. I am new to the java world, from python...so I tend to forget about the importance of claiming the types in java.

Comment: Please don't just use `List<List>`, that still uses raw types. Use `List<List<Integer>>` and always add the _correct_ generic types, not just half and not just `<Object>`. That gives you type safety and less headaches.

Comment: @Tom Thank you. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the List of lists a specific type:

```
List<List> Lgrid = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(LL1, LL2, LL3));
```

Edit: Better practice to use non-raw types:

```
    List<Integer> LL1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2));
    List<Integer> LL2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6));
    List<Integer> LL3 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9));
    List<List<Integer>> Lgrid = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(LL1, LL2, LL3));
    Lgrid.get(0).add(3);
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I overlooked the type of the grid!

Comment: Please, don't use raw types. Add generic parameter `List<List<here>>`